# Magento 2.3.4 : How to add & play Vimeo embed video

Tags: magento2, video

I have a Vimeo video URL. But, I can't able to add in my custom page. How to load and play on the custom page?

Answer (score 0):

if you have static url and that never changed for you then you can use iframe code for displaying video in your custom page.

```
<iframe title="vimeo-player" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/336812660" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

in src, you should put your video link.

If this help then hit like.

Thank you,

Hiren Patel

Comment: this is stackexchange not facebook, one cannot "hit like"

Answer (score 0):

The best way to embed videos like this is with a responsive iframe container.

HTML

```
<div class="embed-container">&nbsp;
<p style="text-align: center;">
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/336812660" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.embed-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```